# How to create alias in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my mysql code.

```
select * from (CITY JOIN COUNTRY ON CITY.COUNTRYCODE=COUNTRY.Code) t;
```

while this is working fine if i remove t.
what is problem in creating alias as t.

Comment: What is `t` and alias for? Did you mean `CITY t JOIN…`?

Answer (score 0):

The parentheses in your `from` clause are merely grouping the `JOIN` operations in the `FROM` clause.  Your query is:

```
select *
from (CITY JOIN
      COUNTRY
      ON CITY.COUNTRYCODE = COUNTRY.Code
     )
```

This is not a subquery and is equivalent to:

```
select *
from CITY JOIN
     COUNTRY
     ON CITY.COUNTRYCODE = COUNTRY.Code;
```

I would advise you not to use parentheses unless they are needed (which is pretty rare).

You would need an alias for a subquery, as in:

```
select *
from (SELECT C.* FROM CITY) C JOIN
     COUNTRY
     ON c.COUNTRYCODE = COUNTRY.Code;
```

Note:  I am not advocating using such a subquery (which is a bad idea for performance reasons in many MySQL versions).  I am merely showing this as an example for the syntax.